# Is it possible to use subquery in leftJoinAndSelect in TypeORM

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

So i've got a project on nestjs and using TypeORM. And my situation is i have a User which have One-to-May relation with UserSubscrption.  Default find query added all subscriptions to User as it should be. So now i want to find one specific subscription, for example last added. So i build this query:

```
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder("user")
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user.settings", "settings")
    .leftJoinAndSelect( 
      subQuery => {
          return subQuery
              .select()
              .from(UserSubscription, "subscription")
              .where("subscription.userId = :id AND subscription.isConfirmed = :isConfirmed", { id, isConfirmed: true })
              .orderBy('"createdDate"', 'DESC')
              .limit(1);
      }, 'subscription', '"subscription"."userId" = "user"."id"')
    .where('user.id = :id', { id });
    const result = await query.getOne(); // await query.execute()
```

First, i try just execute the query and it works fine but all the data not structured

```
[
  {
    user_id: 1,
    user_username: 'name',
    ...
    settings_id: 1,
    settings_ifOnline: true,
    ...
    subscriptions_id: 1,
    subscriptions_subscriptionId: 1,
    ...
  }
]
```

So it's not good.

Then i try query.getOne() but it wont work as i want, it's lost all subscription data

```
User {
  id: 1,
  username: 'name',
  ...
  settings: UserNotificationSettings {
    id: 1,
    ifOnline: true,
    ...
  }
}
```

Also, i tried to add virtual field subscription to user entity and try to use leftJoinAndMapOne:

```
    ...
    .leftJoinAndSelect("user.settings", "settings")
    .leftJoinAndMapOne("user.subscription", 
      subQuery => {
          return subQuery
              .select()
              .from(UserSubscription, "subscription")
              .where("subscription.userId = :id AND subscription.isConfirmed = :isConfirmed", { id, isConfirmed: true })
              .orderBy('"createdDate"', 'DESC')
              .limit(1);
      }, 'subscription', '"subscription"."userId" = "user"."id"')
    ...
```

But with no luck. In docs it's said that "Subqueries are supported in FROM, WHERE and JOIN expressions." but no example is provided. So, i have no idea how to handle this i belive pretty much simple query with TypeORM. Any suggestions? i'm kinda stuck with this. May be there is some better way than buildibg queries?  Thanks.

User.entity

```
 export class User extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
  ...

  // subscription: UserSubscription;

  @OneToMany(type => UserSubscription, subscriptions => subscriptions.user, { cascade:true })
  subscriptions: UserSubscription[];

  @OneToOne(type => UserNotificationSettings, settings => settings.user, { cascade:true })
  settings: UserNotificationSettings;
}
```

UserSubscription.entity

```
export class UserSubscription extends BaseEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(type => Subscription)
  @JoinColumn()
  subscription: Subscription

  @Column()
  subscriptionId: number

  @ManyToOne(type => User, user => user.subscriptions)
  user: User

  @Column({type: 'integer'})
  userId: number

  @Column({ type: 'boolean', default: false })
  isConfirmed: boolean

  ...
}
```

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Any solution there?

Answer (score 16):

Using the `SubQueryFactory` option does not automatically create the `on` clause as the condition as it cannot know what the underlying query's alias is that you're trying to join with. It doesn't have the context afforded by the metadata of `.leftJoinAndSelect('user.photos', 'photos')` because of how it's been written.

Instead, you have to explicitly define the condition. In your case:

```js
const result = await userRepo
                     .createQueryBuilder('user')
                     .leftJoinAndSelect(
                         qb => qb
                            .select()
                            .from(UserPhotos, 'p')
                            .orderBy({ 'p.updatedAt': 'ASC' })
                            .limit(5),
                         'photos',
                         'photos.userId = user.id' // the answer
                     )
                     .getRawMany() // .getMany() seems not working
```

Here is the actual answer:
https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/6767

#### UPDATE

I saw that `.getMany()` is not working when using `SubQueryFactory`. Insted you can use `.getRawMany()`.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with `getMany`? I want the entities, not the raw stuff.

Comment: If you want that an aggregated column shows when using getMany you have to add that column in your entity, otherwise it gets ignored by typeorm.

Comment: @LuisContreras Do you have an example of that?

Comment: Not in code. but the idea is that getMany only match results to the entity. for example if you want to count, even if the typeorm calculates the value correctly is not going to find where to store that value in the entity. so, if you use getRawMany it does not consider this validation and it shows all you query @FedericoPeralta

Answer (score 2):

If you want a subquery in `leftJoinAndMapOne` you can use this workaround:

```js
    const query = this.createQueryBuilder('user')
      .leftJoinAndSelect('user.settings', 'settings')
      .leftJoin(
        subQuery => {
          return subQuery
            .select()
            .from(UserSubscription, 'subscription')
            .where('subscription.userId = :id AND subscription.isConfirmed = :isConfirmed', { id, isConfirmed: true })
            .orderBy('"createdDate"', 'DESC')
            .limit(1);
        },
        'subscription',
        '"subscription"."userId" = "user"."id"'
      )
      .leftJoinAndMapOne('user.subscription', UserSubscription, 'subscription_', 'subscription_.id = subscription.id')
      .where('user.id = :id', { id });
    const result = await query.getOne();
```

Basically you put your subquery in a regular `leftJoin` and then map that join in `leftJoinAndMapOne`

Comment: This answer is the most straight forward if you want to have custom logic in your joins. However, it is a pain that the library doesn't work when you use `.leftJoinAndMapMany()` and a sub query builder. The quick workaround is this answer which is just a `.leftJoin` with a .`leftJoinAndMap...`. However, in larger queries with many joins, doubling the joins just to get mapping to work _really_ slows the query down.