# Typeorm: joined relation data is not showing in final result

Tags: typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I have a `moving` table which is in a one-to-many relation with the `moving_activities` table. `moving_activities` table records all the activities happening on the `moving` table.
I'm trying to fetch all data from moving along with the latest activity from the `moving_activites` table.

My query:

```
this.repository
        .createQueryBuilder('moving')
        .leftJoinAndSelect(
          (subQuery) => {
            return subQuery
              .from(MovingActivityEntity, 'ma')
              .where('ma.moving_id = :movingId', { movingId: id })
              .orderBy('ma.created_at', 'DESC')
              .limit(1);
          },
          'movingActivities',
          'movingActivities.moving_id = moving.id'
        )
        .where('moving.id = :id', { id })
        .getOneOrFail();
```

`MovingEnity`

```
@Entity('movings')
export class MovingEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  readonly id: string = ulid();

  @CreateDateColumn()
  readonly createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  readonly updatedAt: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  historyId?: string;

  @Column({ nullable: true })
  postId?: string;

  // @OneToMany((type) => MovingActivityEntity, (movingActivity) => movingActivity.moving)
  movingActivities: MovingActivityEntity;

}
```

`MovingActivityEntity`

```
@Entity('moving_activities')
export class MovingActivityEntity {
  @PrimaryColumn()
  readonly id: string = ulid();

  @CreateDateColumn()
  readonly createdAt: Date;

  @Column({ nullable: false })
  movingId: string;

  @ManyToOne((_type) => MovingEntity)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'moving_id' })
  moving?: MovingEntity;

  @Column({
    type: 'enum',
    enum: activityTypes,
    default: 'undefined',
  })
  latestActivityType: ActivityType = 'undefined';

  constructor(movingId: string) {
    this.movingId = movingId;
  }
}
```

when I run the query I only get the `movings` table data. there is no `moving_activities` object.

```
MovingEntity {
  id: '01FVV2VPD7SZ87GWR4PQ840PRX',
  createdAt: 2022-02-14T03:01:47.049Z,
  updatedAt: 2022-04-22T07:20:05.000Z,
  historyId: null,
  postId: '01FVV2VPA8M12TV39W4861EVZV',
}
```

I have also tried to map the data in `movingActivities` with `leftJoinAndMapOne` with no luck.

If I use `execute()` in place of `getOneOrFail()` I get the intended result but `execute()` return the raw data.

Answer (score 0):

Custom select work only with raw results.
You can use also `getRawOne()`.

The method leftJoinAndSelect say:

> LEFT JOINs given subquery and add all selection properties to SELECT..

so not add the object but all properties to the selection. These added properties are not in the model that you are getting with `getOne...`, but you can return this data with `getRawOne()`.

Maybe `leftJoinAndMapOne` can be what you looking for.

Try this query:

```js
this.repository
        .createQueryBuilder('moving')
        .leftJoinAndMapOne('moving.movingActivities',
          (subQuery) => {
            return subQuery.select()
              .from(MovingActivityEntity, 'ma')
              .where('ma.moving_id = :movingId', { movingId: id })
              .orderBy('ma.created_at', 'DESC')
              .limit(1);
          },
          'movingActivities',
          'movingActivities.moving_id = moving.id'
        )
        .where('moving.id = :id', { id })
        .getOneOrFail();
```

There is also an old question for the same problem: [61275599](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61275599/is-it-possible-to-use-subquery-in-leftjoinandselect-in-typeorm)

Edit:
Checked in typeorm source code, actually in the current version if we use subquery the mapping is skipped. So the only way to get full results from join with sub query is using getRaw methods.

Comment: I have tried `leftJoinAndMapOne`. This does not work

Comment: @AkashSarkar yeah, i checked and not work, the subquery not support mapping